# MongoDB optimal technique to store a "like" for a post

Tags: php, mongodb

I am new to MongoDB.
I am trying to develop a simple practice project in PHP.

I have two collections as following:

**`users`** collection

Example of a document in users collection:

```
{
   "_id": ObjectId("57f099cf1ccbdd780b000029"),
   "first_name": "Foo",
   "last_name": "Bar",
   "username": "foobar",
   "email": "foobar@gmail.com",
   "password": "$2y$10$5ec2yYQ8Xl1HH3zM6205LupR7hf/xOLLW9vU7VMYiUc317HB6p76e"
}
```

**`posts`** collection

Example of a document in posts collection:

```
{
   "_id": ObjectId("57ef7be11ccbdd4c17000029"),
   "uid": ObjectId("57e6ff571ccbdd6016000029"),
   "content": "Data of the post goes here!",
   "time": NumberInt(1475312609),
   "likes": [],
   "comments": [] 
}
```

The `likes` key saves the user IDs as in array.

The problem I am facing is that, I want to show the unlike button if the user have already liked the post. In that case I have to check that if the user ID of the current user (stored in session) is in the `likes` array.

Right now, I am fetching the whole `likes` array and check for the user ID in PHP.

I was thinking that, what would be the optimal solution for this problem.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: I would create a separate collection for likes.

Comment: Keeping the key value-pair? With key being the post ID and value be the user ID. Are you implying this technique?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can manage the counter on the post collection.
And the optimal to reduce time complexity solution would be to create a different collection.
And user the post ID as the key and User ID as the value.

Then you can perform this operation:

```
db.likes.find({"post_id": "user_id"})
```

This will give you the result for the particular user id and post id combination.

Note: This method is good in terms of time complexity but will use memory as it saves post_id every time.